# Using inquirer in default gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've been refactoring an existing site towards using gulp and npm more efficiently. I'd like to incorporate inquirer into my tasks to define some build alternatives. For now I'm starting simple.

Here is my current gulpfile:

```
//Define our required components
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inq = require('inquirer');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ scope: ['dependencies', 'devDependencies'] });

//Function that retrieves the file for the specifically names task
function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp-tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins);
};

//Call for our tasks
gulp.task('thirdPartyComponents', getTask('ThirdPartyComponents'));
gulp.task('thirdPartyComponents.css', getTask('ThirdPartyComponentsCss'));
gulp.task('buyer.app', getTask('Buyer.App'));
gulp.task('buyer.controllers', getTask('Buyer.Controllers'));
gulp.task('buyer.directives', getTask('Buyer.Directives'));
gulp.task('buyer.filters', getTask('Buyer.Filters'));

//CODE NOTE: Dependent tasks are case-sensitive
gulp.task('default', function () {
    var questions =
        [
            {
                type: 'confirm',
                name: 'minimize',
                message: 'Do you want to minimize the files?',
                default: true
            }
        ];

    inq.prompt(questions).then(function (answers) {
        console.log(answers);
    });
});
```

When I run the task I get this in the output window in the task explorer

```
[16:21:21] Using gulpfile ....
[16:21:21] Starting 'default'...
[16:21:21] 'default' errored after 185 ms
[16:21:21] Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.stdin (node.js:740:17)
    at setupReadlineOptions (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:57:35)
    at module.exports (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:14:40)
    at new module.exports (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js:15:8)
    at Object.promptModule [as prompt] (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js:26:14)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\Gulpfile.js:31:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Projects\BuyerSupplier\BuyerSupplier\Main\Source\BuyerSupplier.site-dev\src\BuyerSupplier.site\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
Process terminated with code 1.
```

I'm not sure why something this straightforward doesnt want to fire off....any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, and its nothing to do with the code directly. I am running inside Visual Studio and was using the Task Runner Explorer to call the default task. This was where I was seeing the issue.

After doing more research, and on a whim, I ran the gulp task from a command window. It completed as expected. Therefore there are still issues within the Task runner with commands that use `process.stdin` command.